# Testing method via spy with mocked collaborators using PowerMock & Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

Trying to figure out the best way to do something that seems pretty simple: test that a specific method is being called on a collaborator from a class under test.  I'm using Mockito (1.9.5) & PowerMock (1.5.1) with JDK 6.

General approach is to set up a partial mock via Mockito `spy`, set internal state via PowerMock `WhiteBox` methods, and then call the method I'm testing: `creatFoo()`.

Simplified the code as much as possible while still getting across gist of what I'm getting at.  Here's the class under test:

```
public class FooGate {
    BlackBox.Factory factory;
    BlackBox.Bar bar;

    public void createFoo(Foo foo) {
        bar = factory.produce(BlackBox.Bar.class);

        bar.create(bbFoo);
    }
    ...
}
```

Here's the test that isn't working:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(FooGate.class)
public class FooGateTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {

        FooGate testGate = Mockito.spy(new FooGate());

        BlackBox.Factory mockfactory = mock(BlackBox.Factory.class);
        BlackBox.Bar mockBar = mock(BlackBox.Bar.class);

        WhiteBox.setInternalState(testGate, BlackBox.Factory, mockFactory);
        WhiteBox.setInternalState(testGate, BlackBox.Bar, mockBar);

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setSetting("x");

        doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
            public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                ... do stuff ...
            }
        }).when(mockBar).create(any(Foo.class));

        // NPE here: seems like bar is null in testGate.
        testGate.createFoo(foo);

        assertStuff(...);

    }
}
```

If I remove the WhiteBox.set... for `Factory` I get an NPE on `factory.produce()`.  So, that seems to be working.

But the `doAnswer()` apparently isn't.  Or something else.

Definitely open to other approaches that accomplish same thing, but would like to know what I'm missing here.

*Note: It doesn't look like it's an issue with imports, so I've omitted them, but if you think  they could be useful, I can include them.*

Comment: Have you tried running with a debugger, to see if the call to `WhiteBox.setInternalState` really is doing what you expect?

Comment: Try the following and report back. 1. don't spy the class under test. I don't see any reason to do so in the above test. 2. add setter methods to the class under test and remove the use of WhiteBox.

Comment: @DavidWallace I did.  Without the `setInernalState(mockFactory)` I get an NPE at `factory.unimportant()`.

Comment: @JohnB **1.** Tried with and without `spy()`, with and without `mock()`; same result.  **2.** BlackBox.Factory and .Bar are 3rd party classes.  There is no reason they would ever be set be a consumer of this class, so I'd rather not create setters for them just for testing.

Comment: My point was to add the setters just to see if that solves the issue. Not a long-term solution but might point you in the right direction.

Comment: @JohnB Right, right.  I didn't mean to assume one thing or the other, and in fact it did point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had was fairly simple.  It was also not possible to see in the first version of this question.

The issue was when `produce()` on the `Factory` I set via `WhiteBox.setInternalState()` was called, that method wasn't properly stubbed, so it was returning null.  So `bar` was null when I tried to call `bar.create()`: hence NPE.

Fixed by properly stubbing `produce()`, in `FooGateTest`:

```
when(mockfactory.produce((Class)anyObject())).thenReturn(mockBar);
```

... and test passes, no errors.